# TrustWalletCore/WalletCore pod in Kotlin Multiplatform - almost no classes

Tags: ios, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, trustwallet

In our Kotlin Mobile Multiplatform project for iOS and Android, we're trying to access TrustWalletCore cocoapod from Kotlin.

```
// build.gradle.kts (:shared)
cocoapods {
   version = "1.0"
   podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
   pod("WalletCore")
}
```

And the Podfile is

```
target 'iosApp' do
  pod 'TrustWalletCore'
end
```

This successfully enables `import cocoapods.WalletCore.*` in **shared/iosMain** - without the above `cocoapods {...}` the import is unavailable.

However, only a **Crypto** class is available from this package (and CryptoMeta which doesn't look too different).
[image: only Crypto class]

By the looks of it, it's **generated** from the Pod/library [by commonizer](https://fossies.org/linux/kotlin/native/commonizer/README.md) in **0_WalletCore.knm** (about 15 `expect` functions in total - a couple here for illustration):

```
@kotlin.commonizer.ObjCCallable public open external expect fun base58Encode(data: platform.Foundation.NSData): kotlin.String { /* compiled code */ }

@kotlin.commonizer.ObjCCallable public open external expect fun generateMnemonicFromSeed(seed: platform.Foundation.NSData): kotlin.String { /* compiled code */ }
```

It has mnemonic-related functionality, as well as `signHash/verifySignature` but not much else.

I was hoping to see - available to import in Kotlin - classes like `HDWallet`, `EthereumSigningInput` etc.
I can use these library classes in Swift, via `pod TrustWalletCore` in Xcode (`import WalletCore`).

WHY can I not get a similar/full set of classes via `native.cocoapods` plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare dependency with `moduleName` parameter:

```kotlin
kotlin {
    cocoapods {
        ...
        pod(name = "TrustWalletCore", version = "3.1.0", moduleName = "WalletCore")
    }
}
```